# Mocking both static and dynamic methods with PowerMock

Tags: java, mocking, easymock, powermock

Let's say we have

```
public class Foo {
   public static Foo getInstance() {...}

   public Bar bar(Baz baz) {...}
}
```

What I want to do is to mock it in my unit tests. I need to mock both static and dynamic methods of a class `Foo`. Mocking `getInstance()` is as easy as

```
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.replace;
import static org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.method;

public class MyTest {

   @Test
   public void myTest() {
      replace(method(Foo.class, "getInstance"))
         .with(method(MyTest.class, "getMockInstance"));
   }

   public static Foo getMockInstance() {
      Foo foo = EasyMock.createMock(Foo.class);
      EasyMock.replay(foo);
      return foo;
   }
}
```

The question is, how to mock `bar` method?

Previous trick with `replace(method(...)).with(method(...))` does not work as it is not designed for dynamic methods.

Trying to mock on top of already mocked class also doesn't work:

```
...
@Test
public void myTest() {
      replace(method(Foo.class, "getInstance"))
         .with(method(MyTest.class, "getMockInstance"));

      Foo foo = Foo.getInstance();  // works well
      Baz baz1 = new Baz();
      Baz baz2 = new Baz();
      EasyMock.expect(foo.bar(baz1)).andReturn(baz2);  // exception thrown
      EasyMock.replay(foo);
}
...
```

Code above throws `AssertionError: Unexpected method call bar`.

So how do I do both? I don't want to put mocking of `.bar(...)` into the `getMockInstance` because in the real world I need some data that is not available from within static `getMockInstance` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are calling replay on your `foo` mock twice, once in the mocked static method `getMockInstance()` and once after you tell mocked `foo` to expect the `foo.bar(bar1)` call.  Try altering the `getMockInstance()` to

```
   public static Foo getMockInstance() {
      Foo foo = EasyMock.createMock(Foo.class);
      return foo;
   }
```

and then telling EasyMock to replay `foo` after you tell it to expect the `bar` method call.  So the MyTest.java would look something like this:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
      replace(method(Foo.class, "getInstance"))
         .with(method(MyTest.class, "getMockInstance"));

      Foo foo = Foo.getInstance();  // works well
      Baz baz1 = new Baz();
      Baz baz2 = new Baz();
      EasyMock.expect(foo.bar(baz1)).andReturn(baz2);  // exception thrown
      EasyMock.replay(foo);
}

  public static Foo getMockInstance() {
      Foo foo = EasyMock.createMock(Foo.class);
      return foo;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is is possible to achieve the same without suppressing replay (e.g. switch back Foo to another mode, add more mock stuff and switch back to replay at the end)?

Comment: The easymock documentation leads me to believe no (http://easymock.org/api/easymock/3.0/org/easymock/IMocksControl.html).  I think its 'best practice' to setup your tests in the order of: 1. create mocks and expect calls. 2. Replay all of your mocks.  3. Perform actual methods.  4. Call EasyMock.verify if necessary.  Testing static methods if always difficult, unfortunately

Comment: Thanks again BuffaloBuffalo for your help.